# Code only works within a DispatchQueue.main.async block, why?

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote this code to select all the text when a user begins editing a UITextField:

```
@IBAction func onEditingBegin(_ sender: Any) {
    print("editing began")
    let textfield = sender as! UITextField
    textfield.selectAll(nil)
}
```

But it wouldn't work until I enclosed the `textfield.selectAll(nil)` line in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    textfield.selectAll(nil)
}
```

Why is that?

I also printed out the name of the thread in `onEditingBegin()` and this was the result:

`<NSThread: 0x60800006c880>{number = 1, name = main}`

So it seems that it is already being fired on the main thread, but the code is still not working unless `textfield.selectAll()` is called inside of the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block.

Comment: That's really strange. Just out of curiosity, what made you even think to put it within an `async` block? I feel like there has to be something that caused you to try that?

Comment: @Pierce this is very strange. For me, I had something similar and I didn't have to do this.

Comment: `UITextField` has a delegate function `didBeginEditing` put the `textField.selectAll(nil)` in there instead.. Right now you are doing it BEFORE editing mode begins.

Comment: I had the same problem even when using the delegate function `didBeginEditing`. Came to the same conclusion as OP, wrapped it in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` and now it works correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real effect of your call to `DispatchQueue.main.async` is to add a tiny, tiny *delay*. This delay, in particular, is exactly long enough to allow the current runloop to finish and the next runloop to start. The action that has caused an event to be sent to you, calling `onEditingBegin`, is thus permitted to *complete*. The text field now *is* editing, and so we are ready for the next step, namely to select its contents.

The trick you've discovered is actually something that is surprisingly often needed in iOS programming. Cocoa is a complicated framework, and manipulations of the interface sometimes can stumble over one another's feet, as here — while the user is starting to edit in the text field, you are trying to select the text field's text. Sometimes we just need the runloop to come around one more time in order to permit the interface to "settle down" before proceeding to the next step.

Comment: My answer here is almost exactly parallel: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15589890/341994

Comment: i don't get it. why is this trick necessary? is it in the apple docs?

Comment: @shoe No, you just have to discover this kind of thing by experimentation. You can't _know_ why it's necessary, because Cocoa's code is closed to you. Working with Cocoa is like a black box; sometimes you just have to poke it and see what happens. In this case, the code wasn't working, presumably because we couldn't select the text until _after_ the field had finished going into edit mode. Allowing the runloop to complete permits that to happen.

Comment: @shoe; Consider the function name: `onEditingBegin` vs. `onEditingDidBegin` or `editingDidChange`..  The OP is trying to set the textfield's selection BEFORE edit mode has been enabled. For example, onEditingBegin might be called before editing started since the function hasn't completed yet. Once the function is complete, editing mode would have started so `editingDidChange` would be fine.  It's kind of like trying to change the navigation bar colour in `viewWillAppear` (view hasn't appeared yet, navBar is nil) instead of `viewDidAppear` (view appeared already, navBar is non-nil).

Comment: @shoe That's kind of a meaningless question. It works when it works. You might want to read this section of my book, which provides some cogent real-life examples: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_delayed_performance

Comment: how is it "kind of a meaningless question"? seems perfectly meaningful to me.  but i think a strong argument can be made that "it works when it works" is kind of a meaningless response

Comment: @shoe; It's a timing issue that will work 99% of the time. The other 1% is entirely dependent on the system and the OS. Who knows when the next run loop will be called. On one system it might not even be needed. On another it might. Then on a different OS, it may not even work at all.. But still.. that 99% chance is worth it. Logically, it is most likely going to work all the time considering that editing mode is enabled AFTER the function is completed. In that case, it's pretty much 100% chance of it working. It would of course be better to put it in `didBeginEditing` (UITextFieldDelegate).

Comment: @Brandon got it. 99% seems good enough for me. thanks Brandon. and the OP did put it in the `didBeginEditing` delegate, they just named the method `onEditingBegin`

Comment: @shoe; Ahh I see. Well then in that case, they have no choice but to use the workaround or else add an observer for the `isEditing` property change and add the code in the callback function. But I'd rather just stick to the async instead of going through all that trouble.